# I get a nil object reference when I dont expect it -ROR

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror

while updating a database from rails console by following commands:

```
user=User.first
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 1
=> nil
```

And then when I update it using

```
user.update_attributes(:email => "example@railstutorial.org", :password => "foobar", :password_confirmation => "foobar")`
```

I get this error:

```
NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of ActiveRecord::Base.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.update_attributes
```

I am trying to learn ROR from mhartl tutorial and this is related to the tutorial. I found similar questions already answered on the site but couldn't make anything out of them. So posting my specific error here.

Comment: So, you obviously have no users in the database.

Answer (score 4):

The `User.first` returns `nil` so you don't get an Object because there is no object in the database! And `nil` doesn't have an `update_attributes` methods because this is inherited by `ActiveRecord::Base`. Your problem is that there is no data in your database!

Comment: Woah slowdown :) Careful of those typos.